# PO files inside contrib modules

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

Situation is that inside contrib modules folder I found out that each module has /translations and inside a .po file which is not cool when it comes to modules update. I want to take out these translations out of each module folder and place them in single location.

My questions is any idea why they were placed there in first place, is this some kinda of convention or? 
Also if I extract them to another folder what type of configuration must be provided ? 
And last question is I assume that simply removing/moving them wont affect translation at all as they were already import into the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research in drupal.org I found out that best way is to place translations in /sites/all/translations. Naming convention is module_name-version-language.po

Moving them out did not affected the current translations as they are already imported into the database.